# How can I use an ATI Radeon HD 6450 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: drivers, 13.04, graphics, radeon, fglrx

Basically, I get a orange/purple/black flickering screen when I try to boot Ubuntu 13.04 with my AMD Radeon HD 6450 without the proprietary drivers, but cannot install the driver from the website without having the graphics card installed.
How, then, could I use my graphics card and install the drivers, despite the flickering screen?

P.S. I tried to go into tty, that only gave me a blank screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using "nomodeset" boot parameter to boot Ubuntu, install the drivers and boot normally.
[What is nomodeset?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)

To add boot parameters temporary at the grub boot menu press “e” while certain menu entry is select. Boot parameter should be added to the end of the line where it says "quiet splash" and to boot with these settings press f10. You can find more guides for setting boot parameters from grub [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

At least you should be able to use command line then. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291889/ati-driver-breaks-unity-fglrx-or-fglrx-updates/291957#291957) are some guides about installing AMD drivers from command line.